# Java how to convert List<Object[]> into a String[]

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I found a lot of ways to `convert List< Object >` to `String[]` but it did't work for `List< Object[] >`.
I'm getting error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Code:

```
public String[] listToArray(List<Object[]> inputList) {
        String[] outputArray = new String[inputList.size()];
        int index = 0;
        for(Object obj : inputList) {
            outputArray[index] = (String) obj;
            index++;
        }
        return outputArray;
    }
```

Comment: every object in your input list is Object[] and not Object as you have it in for loop

Comment: Why do you want to cast a Object[] to String? Can you be more clear on what the elements of the resulting String[] array should be?  (Each String being some representation of Object[], I'm sure you want something other than the default toString implementation...which is a junk hash code). For example, each object could be converted to String and concatenated?

Comment: Can you give us example of input and expected result?

Comment: I was working with CSV file. And I needed to convert List<Object[]> which stores data got from that file. Thanks to NightsWatch, who helped me with solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the changes I have done to your code to overcome the class cast exception and other possible exceptions which may occur. Your list contains object[] and not Object. Hence the casting to String is throwing error. You can avoid it by iterating it at 2 levels, one for every object[] in list and then every object in object[]. As your List is of Object[] type your code to initialize String[] of list size is not correct under all circumstances, you may end up with Array index out of bounds exception, hence I am adding every string to list and then convert the list to array at last step.

```
 public static String[] listToArray(List<Object[]> inputList) {
        List<String> outputList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Object[] obj : inputList) {
            for(Object obj1 : obj)
            {
                outputList.add((String) obj1);
            }
        }
        return outputList.toArray(new String[outputList.size()]);
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do.
Now, I see my mistakes. 
Thanks a lot!